# how to visualize velocity from Lagrangian particle tracking method

Tags: fluid-dynamics, numerical-analysis, molecular-dynamics, microfluidics

I have few particle's position and velocity information as a function of time.
Particle is following a trajectory path, while doing so, one particle may disappear, other particle may appear.

Particle position can be represented as a point and velocity as a vector at that point. If we think of particle position, it is nothing but a point in the flow path or pipe or channel 
(I lack that information or I dont know about it), so I want to reverse engineer point position as kind of geometry position and map or interpolate velocity contour on those points, and see how flow is changing with time.

I dont want to know how to visualize using Matlab or Python.

is there any example or link in Matlab or Python that has reversed engineer Lagrangian particle tracking method.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. What do you mean by "geometry of structure information"?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth it was geometry or structure information. I have edited the post.

Comment: Hi user12 and welcome to scicomp!  If you have both position and velocity both as a function of time,  you could plot the position as a point and velocity as a scaled vector or arrow emanating from the point.  Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding something?  Could you help me to understand how lack of "geometry" information is relevant to your question?

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean. What is the "geometry or structure information" of a particle? Do you want to say that the particle is not just a point-like thing but has a particular shape?

Comment: Can you clarify this question? Are you asking for specific tools that could allow you to visualize the velocity or how to implement a visualizing code using a specific tool (ex: Matlab, Python)? What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth  please find update post.

Comment: @user12: Despite your revisions, it's still not clear to me what you mean by "reverse engineer point position as kind of geometry position". If you have both the point information and the velocity information for all particles that exist at each point in time, presumably you can visualize the flow at each point in time. Given only the particles, are you looking to infer the shape of your simulation domain from the particle positions and velocities?

Comment: @GeoffOxberry yes, given only the particles, I am looking to infer the shape of the simulation domain from the particle positions and velocities

Comment: It looks like user12 is talking about data from a Lagrangian simulation, so the positions of his/her Lagrangian particles indeed define the simulation domain. At a particular instance of time we have a set of N points at some irregular locations \vec{r}_i, where i=1,...,N; and the values of fluid "parcels" velocity at these locations, \vec{V}_i. It sounds like we need to produce a contour plot of some component of V from these data. This is done in MATLAB by constructing Delaunay triangulation of the data. A quick search for MATLAB + Delanay + contour will show some ways to do this.